# iOS list document from directory download?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I want to allow users of my app to send PDF which is in the device.

The problem is, I don't see how to do that...

First, where are the files downloaded ? In which directory ? And how to list these files ?

I see there is NSfileManager but I don't understand how to use that.

I want something like DocumentPicker. (but available for iOS 7)

Comment: You want the app to be able to send PDF..but you are asking where are pdfs downloaded. What do you mean by that? it is a contradiction. 
If you send, you do not download. Please rephrase your question and make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post. I'm talking about a PDF present in the device. (PDF downloaded from mail, or other..)

Answer (score 0):

There is no common central directory in iOS that stores PDF files in way you describe. Nothing.

Each app has its own Documents folder, and apps have absolutely no way to see each others docs folder. So you, as a new pdf manager custom written app will not be able to look into other apps docs folder.

NSFileManager is a standard Cocoa class the handles files in a generic manner.

Comment: Mhhhh I thought that, but how the app 'Document 5' which is a Like file manager do that ?!

Comment: It's not doing that. If you realy read carefully, there is no mention on their website ANYWHERE that THEY are the central folder for everybody., or that have access to other apps data. The app simple has its own "Document" folder, and allows to download files from external sources. Also can push them back to web but never between app nor from some central folder.